# How to return the user DN where it's UID is in a specific group

Tags: openldap

I'm using OpenLDAP which unfortunately doesn't have a "memberOf" property.
Usually when interrogating an Active Directory LDAP, 
you can write a query which is:

```
ldapsearch -Dbinduser -wbinduserpwd -Hldaps://ldapsvr.org -bdn=ldapsvr,dn=org
(&(uid={0},ou=usr,dn=ldapsvr,dn=org)(memberOf=cn=g0001,ou=grps,dn=ldapsvr,dn=org))
```

but now I'm left with a user in:

```
dn: uid=u0001,ou=usr,dn=ldapsvr,dn=org
cn: u0001
```

and a group like:

```
dn: cn=g0001,ou=grps,dn=ldapsvr,dn=org
cn: g0001
memberUid: u0001
memberUid: u0002
```

Does anybody know an ldapsearch query (in particular, the correct filter) to return the user DN?
the closest I can get to is returning the group DN if that memberUid exists, but not the user DN's of users in the group.
My thinking was you could query in ldapsearch to like an SQL:

```
select user.dn 
from dit 
where grp.cn{g001}.memberUid{u0001} = TRUE
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it can be done with less then two queries: the first to get the `uid`, and the second to locate the `dn`.

As a workaround:

1. on OpenLDAP store the groups in `groupOfNames` objects. Those objects allow the `member` attribute, whose content is the member's full `dn`;
2. have a look to the `memberOf` [overlay](http://www.openldap.org/doc/admin24/overlays.html), that allows you to build the reverse memberships (as in Active Directory).